# In c++, Any cross thread synchronisation method that cause major overhead only on write?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to build scheduling system that provides a lookup of thread-local resource.

The lookup is read very often but is updated only when a new thread is add.

using `atomic`/`mutex` causes quite an overhead equally for both read & write.

Are there any way to shift the overhead to write and make read fast?

---

For example, a lookup of `asio::io_context`

```
class Foo {
  public:
  static Foo* instance;
  std::unordered_map<int/*custom thread id*/, asio::io_context* > io_contexts
};

enum class threads:int{
  network, file_io, others_that_may_spawn_after_init_phase...
};

void some_func_called_in_random_thread() {
  //need an unwanted lock here
  asio::post(Foo::instance->io_contexts[threads::network], xxx);
  asio::post(Foo::instance->io_contexts[threads::file_io], yyy);
}

void init_network(){
   auto ptr = new asio::io_contexts();
   //need a lock here
   Foo::instance->io_contexts[trd_network] = ptr;
}

...
```

Comment: Reading an atomic that was not modified since the last read from this core should be *very* cheap since the cache line will already be shared or, at the very least, shareable. Are you sure using an atomic creates significant overhead?!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, I am not sure, I would use atomic if thats the case.

Comment: Have you seen Sean Parent's talk on task systems? If not, I can highly recommend it, I guess you might find some techniques presented there useful, as it's more than a question of a single synchronization primitive
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zULU6Hhp42w